# wordpress page template requre_once() failed

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I want to use a class file in a WordPress page template, but after adding the `require_once()` method, and trying to instance the class, I got

`Fatal error: Class 'ClassName' not found`,

the class file is displayed as html to the output page.

Any idea why this is happening? (I put the page template file and the class file under the theme directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/ClassName.php');`

Edit: Sorry, the file apparently has been found correctly. So then you need the class to be defined in that file looking like this:

```
class ClassName {
   Your code here
}
```

1. Do you have included the class {} construct?
2. Is the name of your class the same as you are trying to instantiate? `$obj = new ClassName();` ?

Comment: yes, i got all that right.and the wired thing is , when i copy the class definition code to the file instead using the require_once() method , it works fine:i can totally instance the class and using its function. like i said , wordpress seems treat it like html code rather than php code.

Comment: how is it with adding the `<?php` tag at the beginning of your file? :D

Comment: yes, i put the `require_once('classFileName')` in `<?php ?>` blcok.

Comment: well, now you should put the class definition in the class file in a php block: `<?php class ClassName { ...`, too.